# When I put RadioButton There is Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a problem. I can't add Radio Button in my project.

**My Xml Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="183dp" />
```

**My Java Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RadioButton rb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

}
```

}

**My Log Chat:**

```
03-26 10:13:10.681 12433-12433/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-26 10:13:10.777 12433-12433/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-26 10:13:10.777 12433-12433/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6249288)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-26 10:13:10.941 12433-12433/com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020008
```

Comment: what is line no 17 in your xml?

Comment: did you simply put a radio button in the xml, without enclosing it in a layout? Post you complete xml code

Answer (score 0):

import Radio button from widget package of android:

```
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama.R;
```

[com.example.wesley.radiobuttonuygulama] is your application package name

Comment: change your radio button id to something like "my_radio_btn" its funny but i cant find any problem in your code

Comment: did you import R class of your project? see my answer again

Comment: your project have error because R class is needed to find index of view id from your layout...rebuild it i should do my homework now i come back later :D wish you solve your problem till i come back...may the force be with you :D